# How to specify 32-bit Windows Debugger in Visual Studio 2012 when doing kernel mode debugging

Tags: visual-studio-2012, 32bit-64bit, windbg, winapi, kernel-mode

I have a 64-bit host/target, but I need to use the 32-bit version of Windows Debugger so I can load some 32-bit debugging tool libraries. This works fine when invoking windbg.exe directly, but when I use the ["Kernel Mode Debugger"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh451163%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) tool in Visual Studio 2012 (which is a 32-bit app btw) it automatically loads the 64-bit Windows Debugger:

> Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 6.2.9200.20512 **AMD64** Copyright
>   (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
> Using 1394 for debugging Checking 1394 debug driver version. Opened
>   \.\DBG1394_INSTANCE44

When this is the tool I really want:

> Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 6.2.9200.20512 **X86** Copyright
>   (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
> Using 1394 for debugging Checking 1394 debug driver version. Opened
>   \.\DBG1394_INSTANCE44

which exists on my system and I can connect with fine when I start windbg.exe directly.

Here's that documentation that supports what I'm trying to do (32-bit debugger on 64-bit host/target): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff539099(v=vs.85).aspx

Anyone know if this can be specified at this time? Or if I have to use windbg.exe directly to accomplish this? Thanks.

Comment: I've resolved this temporarily by copying the "x86" directory in C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Debuggers to a new directory named "x64" after renaming the previous one to "_x64". I'd still like to know if there is an option within visual studio to select this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the accepted answer: I've resolved this temporarily by copying the `x86` directory in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Debuggers` to a new directory named `x64` after renaming the previous one to `_x64`.

I'd still like to know if there is an option within Visual Studio to select this.